# Get content from json with Php conditionally

Tags: php, json, filter, conditional-statements

I am struggling to get some informations/values from a json using php conditionally. To be more detailed, this is my case:
I have a json response that looks like this:

```
{
"IsSuccess": true,
"ResponseCode": 5000,
"ResponseMessage": "OK",
"Data": {
"result": {
"RATE_TO_ALL": [
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "CHF",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "TRY",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "45.51",
"BUY_RATE": "26.24",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "GBP",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "TRY",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "50.71",
"BUY_RATE": "29.24",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "CAD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "CHF",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "0.69",
"BUY_RATE": "0.66",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "AUD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "TRY",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "26.63",
"BUY_RATE": "15.35",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "AUD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "GBP",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "0.54",
"BUY_RATE": "0.51",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "AUD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "CHF",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "0.60",
"BUY_RATE": "0.57",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "AUD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "CAD",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "0.88",
"BUY_RATE": "0.85",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "CAD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "TRY",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "30.88",
"BUY_RATE": "17.80",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "CAD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "GBP",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "0.62",
"BUY_RATE": "0.60",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "CHF",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "GBP",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "0.92",
"BUY_RATE": "0.88",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "USD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "GBP",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "0.83",
"BUY_RATE": "0.80",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "USD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "TRY",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "33.89",
"BUY_RATE": "22.92",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "CHF",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "ALL",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "110.85",
"BUY_RATE": "107.10",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "CAD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "ALL",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "72.90",
"BUY_RATE": "70.40",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "AUD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "EUR",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "0.62",
"BUY_RATE": "0.60",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "AUD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "ALL",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "64.75",
"BUY_RATE": "62.55",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "CHF",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "EUR",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "1.05",
"BUY_RATE": "1.02",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "EUR",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "ALL",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "105.35",
"BUY_RATE": "104.75",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "EUR",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "GBP",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "0.89",
"BUY_RATE": "0.85",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "EUR",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "TRY",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "35.94",
"BUY_RATE": "24.90",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "GBP",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "ALL",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "123.00",
"BUY_RATE": "117.35",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "TRY",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "ALL",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "3.81",
"BUY_RATE": "3.10",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "USD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "ALL",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "99.10",
"BUY_RATE": "97.15",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "USD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "AUD",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "1.57",
"BUY_RATE": "1.52",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "USD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "CAD",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "1.39",
"BUY_RATE": "1.35",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "USD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "CHF",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "0.92",
"BUY_RATE": "0.89",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
},
{
"FROM_CURR_NAME": "USD",
"TO_CURR_NAME": "EUR",
"TREND_RATE": "0",
"SELL_RATE": "0.95",
"BUY_RATE": "0.91",
"PERCENTAGE_RATE": "0.00"
}
],
"LASTUPDATED": "04-11-2023 14:30:03"
}
}
}
```

Using php, I want to retrieve value of SELL_RATE and BUY_RATE for combinations of currencies where FROM_CURR_NAME = "EUR" and TO_CURR_NAME = GBP; also FROM_CURR_NAME = "EUR" and TO_CURR_NAME = TRY; also FROM_CURR_NAME = "USD" and TO_CURR_NAME = GBP.
I have tried to get the values using `$json["Data"]["result"]["RATE_TO_ALL"][17]["BUY_RATE"];` but unfortunately from the json the id [17] is changeing very offten and I am not getting the correct values. Beeing in this situation, the only solution I see is to filter json response based on combination of FROM_CURR_NAME and TO_CURR_NAME, and here I have stopped because at this moment, that is out of my league :-)
Could someone help me with a solution please? What i have now is the followings:

```
$url = "example.com/myjson";
                $curl = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                $headers = array(
                    "Connection: keep-alive",
                    'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"',
                    "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0",
                    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36",
                    'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"',
                    "Accept: */*",
                    "Origin: https://www.example.com",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty",
                    "Referer: https://www.example.com/",
                    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,sq;q=0.8,ro;q=0.7",
                );
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                $resp = curl_exec($curl);
                curl_close($curl);
                $json = json_decode($resp, true);
```

Thank you.

**** EDIT & UPDATED ****

After the accepted response of @Nick, I am struggling getting the foreach results in the content of another text/string that looks like this:

```
$numbering=1;
//Response by Nick Stackoverflow
foreach ($required_rates as ['FROM_CURR_NAME' => $from, 'TO_CURR_NAME' => $to]) {
$buy= $rates[$from][$to]['BUY_RATE'];
$sell= $rates[$from][$to]['SELL_RATE'];
//print "$from => $to : Buy $buy; Sell $sell\n";

//Adding results in an array
$foreachResultArray[] = '{ "id":'.$numbering++.', "currency":"'.$from.'", "buy":'.$buy.', "sell":'.$sell.' }';
}
//Encoding data
$encodeFullInfo = json_encode($foreachResultArray,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
//json data that will be stored in full
$jsondata = '{
"Exchange Rates":
'.$encodeFullInfo.'
}';
```

And the result is as follows:

```
 {"Exchange Rates":[
"{ "id":1, "currency":"EUR", "buy":100.55, "sell":103.45 }",
"{ "id":2, "currency":"USD", "buy":89.90, "sell":96.90 }",
"{ "id":3, "currency":"GBP", "buy":111.65, "sell":122.15 }",
"{ "id":4, "currency":"CHF", "buy":101.85, "sell":110.00 }",
"{ "id":5, "currency":"CAD", "buy":65.85, "sell":71.10 }"
]}
```

As you can see, the problem is that the array from the foreach statement adds quotes before the { and after the } for each result in the loop, and this makes all the statement as json invalide. What I am doing wrong at this stage?
Thank you

Comment: You must never manually craft json strings via string functions or concatenation. Always create json strings with `json_encode()` and only after you are done generating the data payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way (requiring only one pass over each array) to get your results is to re-index your results with the `from` and `to` pairs; then you can simply use that index to look up any desired rates:

```php
$data = json_decode($resp, true);

$rates = array_reduce($data['Data']['result']['RATE_TO_ALL'], function ($acc, $item) {
    $acc[$item['FROM_CURR_NAME']][$item['TO_CURR_NAME']] = array(
        'SELL_RATE' => $item['SELL_RATE'], 
        'BUY_RATE' => $item['BUY_RATE']
        );
    return $acc;
}, array());

$required_rates = [
    ['FROM_CURR_NAME' => 'EUR', 'TO_CURR_NAME' => 'GBP'],
    ['FROM_CURR_NAME' => 'EUR', 'TO_CURR_NAME' => 'TRY'],
    ['FROM_CURR_NAME' => 'USD', 'TO_CURR_NAME' => 'GBP']
];

foreach ($required_rates as ['FROM_CURR_NAME' => $from, 'TO_CURR_NAME' => $to]) {
    $buy = $rates[$from][$to]['BUY_RATE'];
    $sell = $rates[$from][$to]['SELL_RATE'];
    print "$from => $to : Buy $buy; Sell $sell\n";
}
```

Output:

```
EUR => GBP : Buy 0.85; Sell 0.89
EUR => TRY : Buy 24.90; Sell 35.94
USD => GBP : Buy 0.80; Sell 0.83
```

Demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/iM82l)

**Note**

If you're using PHP < 7.1 you won't be able to destructure the associative array, so you'll need to do:

```php
foreach ($required_rates as $rr) {
    $from = $rr['FROM_CURR_NAME'];
    $to = $rr['TO_CURR_NAME'];
    $buy = $rates[$from][$to]['BUY_RATE'];
    $sell = $rates[$from][$to]['SELL_RATE'];
    print "$from => $to : Buy $buy; Sell $sell\n";
}
```

Demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/rcsZN)

**Update**

In terms of producing your desired output (see question edit), you are converting into JSON too often. Just build an array of results and convert to JSON once you are done:

```php
$results = [];
$id = 1;
foreach ($required_rates as ['FROM_CURR_NAME' => $from, 'TO_CURR_NAME' => $to]) {
    $buy = $rates[$from][$to]['BUY_RATE'];
    $sell = $rates[$from][$to]['SELL_RATE'];
    $results[] =  array("id" => $id++, "currency" => $from, "buy" => $buy, "sell" => $sell);
}
$json_data = json_encode(array('Exchange Rates' => $results));
```

Output (for the input data):

```
{
    "Exchange Rates": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "buy": "0.85",
            "sell": "0.89"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "buy": "24.90",
            "sell": "35.94"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "currency": "USD",
            "buy": "0.80",
            "sell": "0.83"
        }
    ]
}
```

Demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UuDQM)

Comment: Thank you for your reply sorry for my delaied reply. Was out of country for a few days. It works now but I am struggling to get it integrated in a context like this one: `{
      "Exchange rates": [                                                                           **result of the foreach **                                                                                                                      ]
      }`      Any extra help for this matter please? Thank you

Comment: @Kleidi no worries at all... you could add `$rates = []` before the `foreach`, then in the `foreach` replace `print` with `$rates[] =`. That will give you those output strings in the array. If you want something different, edit your question with what it is and make another comment here when you've done and I'll modify this answer to suit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Edited the first post with the new issue/problem. Thank you @Nick

Comment: @Kleidi You're converting to JSON too often; you just need to do it once at the end. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `forEach` loop

```php
$rates = $json['Data']['result']['RATE_TO_ALL'];
foreach ($rates as $rate) {
    $from_curr_name = $rate['FROM_CURR_NAME'];
    $to_curr_name = $rate['TO_CURR_NAME'];
    $sell_rate = $rate['SELL_RATE'];
    $buy_rate = $rate['BUY_RATE'];
    echo "$from_curr_name to $to_curr_name: Sell rate:$sell_rate, Buy rate: $buy_rate";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_reduce()` is one cycle of the data, then calling `foreach()` is another cycle over the data, as demonstrated in Nick's answer, is doing more loops than necessary. This task can be done in a single loop and without generating a temporary lookup array of all conversion rates.

Loop over the RATE_TO_ALL subarray, check if the current row's FROM_CURR_NAME AND TO_CURR_NAME are identical to one of the rows in the white list. If so, cache that index, add one to that index if you don't want to start from zero, then push the desired data into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bdDs1))

```
$data = json_decode($resp, true);

$whitelist = [
    ['FROM_CURR_NAME' => 'EUR', 'TO_CURR_NAME' => 'GBP'],
    ['FROM_CURR_NAME' => 'EUR', 'TO_CURR_NAME' => 'TRY'],
    ['FROM_CURR_NAME' => 'USD', 'TO_CURR_NAME' => 'GBP']
];

$result = [];
foreach ($data['Data']['result']['RATE_TO_ALL'] as $row) {
    $needle = ['FROM_CURR_NAME' => $row['FROM_CURR_NAME'], 'TO_CURR_NAME' => $row['TO_CURR_NAME']];
    if (($i = array_search($needle, $whitelist, true)) === false) {
        continue;
    }
    $result[] = [
        "id" => $i + 1,
        "currency" => $row['FROM_CURR_NAME'],
        "buy" => $row['BUY_RATE'],
        "sell" => $row['SELL_RATE']
    ];
}
// sort($result); // if you care about sorting by id values
var_export($result);
```

Nest the result array inside of an associative parent, then json_encode everything, use:

```
echo json_encode(['Exchange Rates' => $result], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```